# PHP URL rewrite redirecting to wrong file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following files in my root folder:

```
listing_location.html
listing_location.php
```

I am using the following link from other page to access to redirect to `listing_location.php`
< a href="listing_location/< ? php echo "$_SESSION["listing_id"]; ?>" > location < / a >

below is the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^listing_location/([0-9]+)/?$ listing_location.php?listing_id=$1
```

But when I click the link it redirects me to `listing_location.html/{some-number}` and gives 404 error.

Comment: Where is the link mentioned by following link?

Comment: Please provide the whole code in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Your webserver (Apache?) is trying "known" file extensions first and finds the .html. You need to deactivate this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, It is Apache. How do I deactivate this behavior?.  I also have another rewriterule along with one mentioned above it works fine though they are 2 files with .html and .php extensions. its only with this I am having issues.

Comment: @Rijul : Here is all the code in .htaccess.   RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule ^pricing/([0-9]+)/?$ pricing.php?listing_id=$1  RewriteRule ^listing_location/([0-9]+)/?$ listing_location.php?listing_id=$1

Comment: @Rijul: I have updated question with the link

Comment: Add `Options -Multiviews` to the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Mike Rockett thanks a lot. Multiviews was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling content negotiation will probably solve your problem.Try this.

```
Options -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^pricing/([0-9]+)/?$ pricing.php?listing_id=$1 
RewriteRule ^listing_location/([0-9]+)/?$ listing_location.php?listing_id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rijul. MultiViews option was the solution for it.